# longtabu alignment cell won't get to the center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn, longtabu

I'm using tabu package. The inside of the every cell doesn't get to the center except for the second and the third. And also the line for closing the table doesn't show. Can anybody help me to fix it?

here's my code:

```
\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt {|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|}

\caption{Tabel pengujian perubahan nilai $poolSize$}
\label{tab:uji_perubahan_mutrate}\\

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Nilai $poolSize$}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Rata-rata nilai \textit{fitness}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Standar Deviasi}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Waktu Eksekusi (ms)}}}\\ \cline{2-3}
                                                                                        & Jenis Mesin & Nilai \textit{fitness} & & \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- lanjutan}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Nilai $mutRate$}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Rata-rata nilai \textit{fitness}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Standar Deviasi}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Waktu Eksekusi (ms)}}}\\ \cline{2-3}
                                                                                        & Jenis Mesin & Nilai \textit{fitness} & & \\ \hline
\endhead

\hline
\endlastfoot

\multirow{4}{*}{50} & MC1 & $-8879.91$ & $307.56$ & 968\\
                                    & MC2 & $-6948.41$ & $232.06$ & 560\\
                                    & MC3 & $-9038.94$ & $301.54$ & 662\\
                                    & MC4 & $-8056.39$ & $29.34$ & 490\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{100} & MC1 & $-8923.99$ & $253.71$ & 1591\\
                                    & MC2 & $-6952.59$ & $235.55$ & 1085\\
                                    & MC3 & $-9074.79$ & $321.58$ & 1336\\
                                    & MC4 & $-8079.78$ & $29.73$ & 1020\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{200} & MC1 & $-8900.99$ & $231.72$ & 3133\\
                                    & MC2 & $-6966.78$ & $210.47$ & 2160\\
                                    & MC3 & $-9156.77$ & $273.89$ & 2832\\
                                    & MC4 & $-8087.58$ & $27.45$ & 2069\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{400} & MC1 & $-8824.43$ & $319.14$ & 6312\\
                                    & MC2 & $-6894.05$ & $243.90$ & 4432\\
                                    & MC3 & $-9206.41$ & $230.69$ & 5679\\
                                    & MC4 & $-8109.32$ & $19.93$ & 4265\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{800} & MC1 & $-8928.02$ & $244.72$ & 13740\\
                                    & MC2 & $-7003.61$ & $224.54$ & 10712\\
                                    & MC3 & $-9105.77$ & $299.83$ & 13881\\
                                    & MC4 & $-8126.01$ & $16.48$ & 10145\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{1600} & MC1 & $-8993.31$ & $184.42$ & 35095\\
                                    & MC2 & $-6979.81$ & $235.70$ & 25039\\
                                    & MC3 & $-9250.08$ & $203.56$ & 36045\\
                                    & MC4 & $-8140.90$ & $8.01$ & 26832\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{3200} & MC1 & $-8975.11$ & $279.18$ & 118560\\
                                    & MC2 & $-7048.33$ & $193.06$ & 97475\\
                                    & MC3 & $-9181.94$ & $275.81$ & 119472\\
                                    & MC4 & $-8140.92$ & $19.60$ & 91147\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{6400} & MC1 & $-8939.97$ & $281.94$ & 292329\\
                                    & MC2 & $-6933.66$ & $266.37$ & 286887\\
                                    & MC3 & $-9184.78$ & $311.50$ & 293889\\
                                    & MC4 & $-817.40$ & $11.09$ & 274224\\


\end{longtabu}
\FloatBarrier
```

and here is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The use of `tabu` is tricky and since it is not maintained, it is not recommended to use ...

Your problem arise because column headers is to wide. With use of `makecell` and its macro `thread` Ibroke heads of last two column into two line. After this it seems that the result is far better as before. I also change table to fixed width (`\textwidth`) and exploit possibility to put columns in "math mode" (and with this the signs `$` in each cells are surplus.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{array,makecell,multirow,longtable,tabu}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%1.2

    \begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {@{}|X[c]|X[c]|X[c,$]|X[c,$]|X[c,$]|@{}}

\caption{Tabel pengujian perubahan nilai $poolSize$}
\label{tab:uji_perubahan_mutrate}\\

    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Nilai  \textit{poolSize}}} 
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Rata-rata nilai \textit{fitness}}} 
        &   \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\thead{Standar\\ Deviasi}}
            &   \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\thead{Waktu\\ Eksekusi (ms)}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & Jenis Mesin & Nilai \textit{fitness} & & \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Nilai  \textit{poolSize}}}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Rata-rata nilai \textit{fitness}}}
        &   \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\thead{Standar\\ Deviasi}}
            &   \multirow{2}{\hsize}{\thead{Waktu\\ Eksekusi (ms)}} \\
    &   Jenis Mesin 
        &   Nilai \textit{fitness}  &   &                           \\ 
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\endlastfoot

\multirow{4}{*}{50} & MC1 & -8879.91 & 307.56 & 968\\
                                    & MC2 & -6948.41 & 232.06 & 560\\
                                    & MC3 & -9038.94 & 301.54 & 662\\
                                    & MC4 & -8056.39 & 29.34 & 490\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{100} & MC1 & -8923.99 & 253.71 & 1591\\
                                    & MC2 & -6952.59 & 235.55 & 1085\\
                                    & MC3 & -9074.79 & 321.58 & 1336\\
                                    & MC4 & -8079.78 & 29.73 & 1020\\
\end{longtabu}
    \end{document}
```

I consider only part of table (to spare space here). Obtained result is:

[image]

The purpose of used `showframe` is only to show page layout. In real case it should be omitted.